# Open URL in new safari tab - safari extention

Tags: safari-extension

generaly i ask exactly the same question as here:

[Safari extension: Event for a completely new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148711/safari-extension-event-for-a-completely-new-tab)

in this answer (case 3) he guide to listen click event inside inject.js.

can someone show this implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation I used for one of my previous extensions:

1. Create a `global.html` file, and inside the Extension Builder, select that file under the **Extension Global Page** section:

[image: Global Page Settings]

2. Source for `global.html`:

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>My Extension</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <script>
        function messageHandler(event) {
          var newTab = null;
          var url = null;

          if (event.name === "open_new_tab") {
            url = event.message;
            newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab();
            newTab.url = url;
          }
        }

        safari.application.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
       </script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Create an `extension.js` file, and add it to the **Injected Extension Content -> End Scripts** section:

[image: end scripts]

4. Source for `extension.js`:

   ```
   (function() {
     // ... rest of you extension code 
     openNewTabWithUrl("http://google.com")

     function openNewTabWithUrl(url) {
       safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("open_new_tab", url);
     }
   }());
   ```

---

This will send a message containing a URL from your `extension.js` to `global.html`, which will pick up the message and open the new tab.